# Count cells in a column that contain certain text only for a certain month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to count cells in column E that contain the word "Yelp" only for a certain month (January in this case).

As there will be a different number of new patients each month, I cannot set set a range limit e.g E4:E33. As this "E33" number will change, I would like it to be just E (entire column) so we don't have to change the formula manually each month.

I tried different variations of COUNTIFS(MONTH(D4:D), "=1", E4:E, "Yelp") but it doesn't work. Using something like "filter" would requires manually changing the formula each month so I can't use that.

- [This formula only counts how many times "Yelp" appears in a column
  but isn't conditional on month.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akh7C.png)
- [Data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huupR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
First add a column (let's say F) that returns the month of the date (D)

F1=`MONTH(D1)` (and drag it down)

Then, count:

```
=COUNTIFS(F:F;4;D:D;'Yelp');
```

That means: count only when month is 4 and source is Yelp

**EDIT:**

I assume you'd want to filter by year as well. In that case, add a column that returns the year:

G1=`YEAR(D1)`  (and drag it down), and then:

```
=COUNTIFS(F:F;4;G:G;2018;D:D;'Yelp');
```

That means: count only when month is 4, year is 2018 and source is Yelp

**EXPLANATION:**

Syntax of COUNTIFS is:

> COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
>
> The COUNTIFS function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> criteria_range1    Required. The first range in which to evaluate the
>   associated criteria.
>
> criteria1    Required. The criteria in the form of a number,
>   expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be
>   counted. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, ">32", B4,
>   "apples", or "32".
>
> criteria_range2, criteria2, ...    Optional. Additional ranges and
>   their associated criteria. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.

From: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: Had the idea of adding an extra column to convert the months to numbers in a new column (and the formula =COUNTIFS(D4:D,1,E4:E,"Yelp") works) but was trying to see if I could make my sheet cleaner by doing something like month = 1. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=sumproduct((month(d4:d999)=1)*(e4:e999="yelp"))
'alternate with fully dynamic ranges
=sumproduct((month(d4:index(d:d, match(1e99, d:d)))=1)*(e4:index(e:e, match(1e99, d:d))="yelp"))
```

Avoid full column references with SUMPRODUCT.

[image]

Comment: Neither of those sumproduct formulas worked (columns are correct) but I played around with the syntax of the formula but it is not responsive. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: I tested them on your sample data and they both worked for me. See above. In fact, this is a pretty familiar sumproduct formula; it is quite common.